# Wrong reports by fastreport

Tags: asp.net, fastreport

We are using fastreport as report-engine for our asp.net-mvc-webapplication. Since months we are encountering heavy problems in using fastreport. Reports are shown in a seperate tab. They always include the fastreport-bar containing the refresh-button. This fastreport-refresh button refreshs the report by using the internal cache of fastreport. But at this point something is going wrong:

When the user refreshs the report a completely different report is shown. This refresh is a fastreport-function and does not involve any of our sourcecode. Users using the reports seems also having trouble with their session. They are regular asked to relogin since the session/authentication is not valid any more - users don't using any reports do not have these issues. Refreshing by browser is no problem.

Since we have not yet found a solution in collaboration with fastreport we are looking for other users encountering this issue and may have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can send your message on support.fast-report.com. Also attach test project there.